# Injection fails in Cuckoo Sandbox

Tags: sandbox, malware, malware-detection, cuckoo

I have a problem when analysing .doc file. with cuckoo sandbox. Here is a link of the cuckoo log: https://img3.picload.org/image/pwarlpp/index.jpeg

As you can see the QueueUserAPC injection fails, but I can't figure out why. Any ideas?

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest first you should submit your sample to malwr.com (which is basically online cuckoo), to rule out the possibility that something wrong with your own VM.

Comment: malwr.com gives me results. I'm pretty sure that it is a VM or cuckoo problem as an injection fails with an error, but i have no cue how to handle that and the official cuckoo board seems to be down :/ so i'm happy with every advise

Comment: if malwr.com gives you results with no error, so I guess the problem in VM, assuming your cuckoo version is updated.
Did malwr.com execute your file in win XP? .. I see from the pic that your VM is win7, is that true?